# Mysqli .Field value not getting updated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to update a field when particular function is called but its value is not getting updated in db .  And also no errors showing up . Field type is text .
I tried by adding new field to table and then updated that field in my query and it worked fine, but after some time same issue with new field .

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE sales_flat_quote SET extra_params = 'aaa',new_params = 'bbb' WHERE entity_id = 362214") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Above query was working earlier but later it doesn't update the value in database and if you run query directly on phpmyadmin it works fine .

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stack overflow. It's hard for anyone to help you without seeing your code. Please update your question including the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your syntax, you forgot to close the double quote:

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE sales_flat_quote SET extra_params = 'aaa',new_params = 'bbb' WHERE entity_id = 362214") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

This should work. Syntax coloring is your friend ;)

Comment: I'd like to add that if this did not show any error, the only possible reason would be that error reporting is turned off.

Comment: Typing mistake i forgot to close double quote . Now its updated